# How do you raycast from an object ignoring only that object (Unity3d)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, raycasting, gameobject

How can I raycast from a gameobject, while ignoring ONLY that gameobject (in Unity)?
I am creating a script that detects which side of the gameObject is collided with. I am using a raycasting script that I created to achieve this. I thoroughly understand layers in Unity, so please no explanations on using layers.

Here is the reason why layers will not achieve my goal: So lets say I have one enemy prefab that sends raycasts ignoring its own layer. If I only have one enemy instantiated (unlikely), everything will work fine. So lets say I have two of the same enemy instantiated. Their layers are the same, so it will NOT detect the other enemy as an object, and whatever I needed to do on a collision will not happen (e.g. turn the enemies direction around).

How can I raycast from a gameobject, while ignoring ONLY that gameobject? If this is not possible, how can I create a collision detection script that returns the side of the gameObject that was collided with (e.g left, right, top, or bottom)?

Thank you so much for any support/answers. It is greatly appreciated as this is a problem that I have run into a couple times now, and have found no reasonable answer to.

=========================================================================
EDIT:

I found that if you go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2d and Uncheck the box that says "Raycasts Start In Colliders" it solves this issue. I am not sure how to close the question...

Comment: The way to close the question is to put your "edit" as an answer to your own question. Then, 48 hours later, you can "accept" your own answer as being correct. This might help future developers with the same questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if you go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics2d and Uncheck the box that says "Raycasts Start In Colliders" it solves this issue.